# Routing an user in a single page application using the adress bar

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router

I have a backend using express to serve a static directory, to the path `/`, in which is contained a single page frontend. This backend also serves an API REST.

The frontend is built in React, and uses react-router to route the user from the different views of the web application.

If my react-router have two entries, let say `/app` and `/config`,

how can I redirect the client to that view of the application, if the user enters directly the URL in the web browser's address bar?

Right now, if I do that, Express gets the request and obviously returns a 404 message, as the single page is served to `/` path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to resolve that is to always (even on 404s) send to user the `index.html` in your express route handlers.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25499007/2624575

However, you need to take care of some things:

1) Your React Router code should start to handle 404s: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37491381/2624575

2) You need to handle correctly the path to your assets (icons, css, js, etc), otherwise you'll send the same `index.html` to those kind of resources (which will make your page render incorrectly)

3) Make sure that `react-router` is using `browserHistory` (the history that doesn't use hashes `#`), This way React will be able to render your routes correctly

Hope it helps!

Comment: So, just to clarify: Do I have to get rid of express static serving, and check at the frontend the path of the request?

Comment: @lilezek you still need to have express static serving (because all your assets need to be served by express). You just need to add a rule to always serve `index.html`, even on 404s. You problem now is that express is treating "/app" and "/config" as 404s, but you needed `index.html` instead. Do you understand?

Comment: Yes, I understood that part but, do react-router will route the user to the application view from the address bar after giving the `index.html`?  Do I have to do something additionally in the frontend?

Comment: Sure! Once it has loaded your javascript, `React Router` will look to your url (in this case, `/app` and `/config`) and will check if your routes match the given url. If it matches, it will render your route. Just make sure you're using `browserHistory` (updated my answer with that).